# What happen when mobile provision expire?

Tags: iphone, adhoc

I have an ad hoc build sent to some persons what will happen when the mobile provision will expire? He ca run the app after that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No he won't.... you'll have to make a new provisioning profile and re-build. That's the point in an adhoc distro, its mean for testing and doesn't last forever. If they want the full app they'll have to download it off the app store. If you want to give it away for free there's a special feature where you can create free download coupons or something similar in itunes connect.

Comment: Thanks man. I wonder if I renew the mobile provision I must also do an other build?

Comment: you will have to I would assume.